# Have a Syntax problem related to an event which I cannot find

Tags: mysql

The execution gives a error (Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1) I don't know what is wrong with it so I was hoping a new set of eyes could help. The execution of the procedurees without the event works fine so its something to do with the event.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT Daily_procedures
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)  + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  DO 
    CALL sp_MessageSender();
    CALL sp_DataMapper();
    CALL sp_PaymentAutomation();
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I am just using mysql workbench currently. That should not be a problem then right?

Comment: You're right. I think the cause is something else. You're missing the `begin` keyword after `do`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html):

> As with stored routines, you can use compound-statement syntax in the
>   DO clause by using the BEGIN and END keywords

So you should wrap your event body into BEGIN/END like this:

```
DO
  BEGIN 
    CALL sp_MessageSender();
    CALL sp_DataMapper();
    CALL sp_PaymentAutomation();
  END//
```